# Android Studio 3.1.2 problems problems with layout editor and gradle.build

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my Android Studio from 3.0 to 3.1.2
I really expected some bug fixes & some new features. But I was wrong...

The Layout Editor is sooo buggy. It used to work so fluently but now the UX is became so bad.
The AVD is also having trouble booting, installing apps. AVD even crashes the OS several times within an hour...

So, I downloaded the 3.0 version again and installed. But the problem is, every time after creating a new project, this error shows up:

[gradle problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unGWl.png)

I know, how to fix this error but doing the fix every time is kind of a hastle. So, I'm actually looking for two things here:

1. Permanently set these things into gradle.build (app):

   compileSdkVersion 27

   targetSdkVersion 27

   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
2. Or I want to update Android Studio to 3.1.2 but not the layout editor.

Any way to do any of these 2 things?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's helping for you(**add in build.gradle**) :

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

or :

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I know the solution. But I just don't want to solve it everytime creating a new project...